# MySql handling horizontal date related columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table which for holds data related data for different companies. The table structure is as follows:

```
companyId, lineItem, col01, col02, col03 ... col60
```

Sample data could be as follows:

```
001, date, 05/01/2021, 02/01/2021, 11/01/2020, 08/01/2020, ...
001, revenue, 20000, 19000, 19500, 18000, ...
002, date, 01/01/2021, 10/01/2020, ...
002, revenue, 13000, 12000, ...
```

(Dates are in MM/dd/yyyy)

What I need to be able to do is select the revenue record for a given company at a certain date. For example if I need the value for the 02/20/2021 it would retrieve the revenue value for the 1st date **before** the 20th Feb then for company 1 it would retrieve 19000 (col02) and company 2 13000 (col01).

Not being a SQL dev I do not know if there is any arcane magic in MySql which would allow me to do this easily or (being a java dev) whether I should for each company:

1. Get the date record
2. Check each col01 ... col60 until I find the date preceding the request date. save that column number
3. Use a massive case statement to return the correct column value of the revenue record.

Comment: Are you stuck with this table design?  With respect, it's an awful design. If you can change it before you get many rows in your table, your future as the maintainer of this system will have far fewer meltdowns, struggles, and angry users. Seriously. You want rows with one companyId, one date, and one revenue data point per row.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the comment. No - I am not stuck with this table design and could change it. I would rather not do so because it is data which is displayed often and in the flat format of the current table design. Unless I could create a view which converts what you suggest into the flat table ... ? But like I said I am not a whizz with sql.